# Java Jersey Jax-WS not receiving JSON parameters

Tags: java, json, maven, jersey, jax-ws

I inherited a large project with many web services.  Seems they were created with Jersey Jax-WS.  I'm tasked with making one of them accept JSON as a POST request.  I can't figure out why the parameters are not received.

I'm using SoapUI to send the request RESTful request.  I created a REST project and set the needed Endpoint and Resource values.  The Media Type dropdown field is set to application/json.  Here is the JSON string I've placed in the textarea immediately below the Media Type field:

```
{"corp":" 877310","rateCodes":["N6","3Z"],"headend_designator":" 238005"," eqp_protocol_aiu":"M3","eqp_typ_aiu":"JD"}
```

Now in my java file called BsgHandleResource

```
@WebService
@Singleton
@Path("/bsghandle")
public class BsgHandleResource {
```

Further down I have this method:

```
@POST
@Path("/getBsgHandles")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public BsgHandleResponse getBsgHandlesJson(
        @PathParam("appkey") String appkey,
        @PathParam("rateCodes") final List<String> rateCodes,
        @PathParam("corp") String corp,
        @PathParam("headend_designator") String headend_designator,
        @PathParam("eqp_protocol_aiu") String eqp_protocol_aiu,
        @PathParam("eqp_typ_aiu") String eqp_typ_aiu,
        @PathParam("forceUpdate") boolean forceUpdate) {

    HttpServletRequest request = getRequestObject();

    logger.debug("getBsgHandlesJson() called for rateCodes="
            + rateCodes.toString() + " from ip" + request.getRemoteAddr());

    return processGetBsgHandleByRateCode(appkey, rateCodes, corp, 
        headend_designator, eqp_protocol_aiu, eqp_typ_aiu, 
                    forceUpdate, request);
}
```

When I send the request from SoapUI, the output I see in the log file is:

```
getBsgHandlesJson() called for rateCodes=[]...
```

My pom.xml file contains these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone suggest what I am missing?

Edit: regarding user2004685 suggestion, my code now looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/getBsgHandles")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public BsgHandleResponse getBsgHandlesJson(BsgHandleRequest obj) {

    HttpServletRequest request = getRequestObject();

    logger.debug("getBsgHandlesJson() called for rateCodes="
            + obj.getRateCodes().toString() + " from ip" + request.getRemoteAddr());

    return processGetBsgHandleByRateCode(obj.getAppkey(), obj.getRateCodes(), obj.getCorp(), 
        obj.getHeadendDesignator(), obj.getEqpProtocolAiu(), obj.getEqpTypAiu(), 
                    obj.getForceUpdate(), request);

}
```

But now I don't even get any logger output.  I do get the following error in the soapui response:

```
<data contentType="text/plain" contentLength="343"><![CDATA[Unrecognized field "headend_designator" (Class com.our.company.oss.vcwh.queryservice.billing.BsgHandleRequest), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@6bb342eb; line: 1, column: 65] (through reference chain: com.our.company.oss.vcwh.queryservice.billing.BsgHandleRequest["headend_designator"])]]></data>
```

Here are the fields in BsgHandleRequest.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "bsgHandleRequest")
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)
public class BsgHandleRequest {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<String> rateCodes;
    private String corp;
    private String headend_designator;
    private String eqp_protocol_aiu;
    private String eqp_typ_aiu;
    private String appkey;
    private boolean forceUpdate;
```

Here is the getter and setter for headend_designator.  I don't see anything wrong or different from any of the other ones.

```
public String getHeadendDesignator() {
    return headend_designator;
}
public void setHeadendDesignator(String headend_designator) {
    this.headend_designator = headend_designator;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no path parameter in your path `@Path("/getBsgHandles")` and you are trying to use `@PathParam`. You should be using a POJO Object instead.

Make a new POJO Class for your Request Object:

```
public class MyRequestObject {
    private String appkey;
    private List<String> rateCodes;
    private String corp;
    private String headend_designator;
    private String eqp_protocol_aiu;
    private String eqp_typ_aiu;
    private boolean forceUpdate;

    /* Constructor */
    public MyRequestObject() {}

    /* Getter-Setters */
}
```

Change your code like this to make use of your POJO Object:

```
@POST
@Path("/getBsgHandles")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public BsgHandleResponse getBsgHandlesJson(MyRequestObject obj) {

    HttpServletRequest request = getRequestObject();

    LOGGER.debug("getBsgHandlesJson() called for rateCodes="
            + obj.getRateCodes().toString() + " from ip" + request.getRemoteAddr());

    return processGetBsgHandleByRateCode(obj.getAppkey(), obj.getRateCodes(), obj.getCorp(), 
        obj.getHeadendDesignator(), obj.getEqpProtocolAiu(), obj.getEqpTypAiu(), 
                    obj.getForceUpdate(), request);
}
```

Comment: Ah... that makes a lot of sense.  But I did what you said and now nothing happens.  Don't even get any logger output.  I will edit my post to show.

Comment: I was watching the log file (tail -f) while executing the request and nothing showed up.  There was no error or stack trace.

Comment: I got nervous about having BsgHandleResponse do double duty as the request object as well, so I wrote a separate one with only the applicable getters and setters.  However, now it gives a different error.  I put in the edits above.

Comment: It seems like it is not able to see `headend_designator`. Try removing the `_` and changing it to something like `headendDesignator` and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, that worked!. I can't believe json has an issue with underscores?  But now it returns an empty bsgHandleList array.  "bsgHandleList": [],  It's soap counterpart works fine.